# Why are the X11 colours different from Wikipedia's?

Tags: xorg

In [this Wikipedia article it gives a bunch of X11 colours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) but they are different from the ones on my FreeBSD system. For example I have no "aqua" or "fuchsia" but, e.g. aquamarine1, etc. and many other numbered colours. Why is that?

Comment: you. have. got. to. be. kidding. me.

Comment: @hop: i. am. not. kidding. you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this page as color reference when looking for an X11 color:

http://sedition.com/perl/rgb.html

Answer (score 5):

The article explains it pretty well

> These charts are not a standard set of
>   colors to be found on any X Window
>   system. Rather it is the standardised
>   "X11 colors" accepted by browsers
>   following the HTML and CSS standards.
>   This set is cut down and rationalised,
>   and has a few differences from a
>   typical rgb.txt...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names

Comment: Then it goes on to give only four differences and does not mention aqua or fuchsia aren't in the list.